# Creating a scrollable gridview in a fragment in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and have been looking at tutorials online. I am looking for a gridview which has a scrollable interface, however, I am looking to implement it into a fragment instead of activity and it does not work without the extends AppCompatActivity so looking for suggestions on how to make it with a fragment.

Here is the code of the gridview in an activity using extends AppCompatActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout mainGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
        //setToggleEvent(mainGrid);
    }

    private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityOne.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info","This is activity from card item index  "+finalI);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far when I try to integrate it with fragment.

```
 public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

GridLayout mainGrid;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container,false);


        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
        //setToggleEvent(mainGrid);
    }

    private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityOne.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info","This is activity from card item index  "+finalI);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Errors being shown

[error part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWZ2t.png)

[error part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBerI.png)

Comment: Is you facing any error while you implementing in fragment?

Comment: edited*********

Comment: Is it give you any error? If yes then post the error-log or screenshot.

Comment: @DavidG mention error which you faced.

Comment: added a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will faced the compile-time error because you have to complete your other work before you return the inflated view in your `onCreateView()` method of your fragment like this:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

GridLayout mainGrid;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container,false);


        mainGrid = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
     return view;
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ActivityOne.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info","This is activity from card item index  "+finalI);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note:-** Please make sure that you have added dependency for the CardView
>   inside the build.gradle file like this.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: where it states MainActivity.this - I need to change this to make it DashboardFragment but 'this' does not work after it??

Comment: yes bro thanks! I did not add the required line of code for the cardView to the build.gradle file which is the reason it did not work

Comment: if you find my answer helpful to you then you can mark it as accepted or up-vote so future visitors can easily find the helpful answers